# How to add korean keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-layout, system-settings

How do I add the korean keyboard typing system? I'm currently usins ubuntu 11.10.

I have tried adding the korean keyboard under setting>keyboard layout, but It doesn't allow me to type in korean.

Comment: Just a quick info, using a key like tab,control or caps-lock etc. after typing 2 Korean syllables prevents them from being separated.
It's not the best way to handle this 'bug' but at least it's better than having to go back and delete spaces between each syllable.

Comment: If you've followed the instructions below and the Korean layout is still behaving like Qwerty, go into Text Entry Settings and make sure you are using `Korean (Hangul)`, not `Korean`.

Answer (score 10):

I tried to find the answer to this last night and I got the same problem as you have. I having been trying again this morning. Is this what you want to do?

ㅂㅈㄷㄱ쇼 that is qwerty. Here is what I did:

1) Use System Settings>Language Support to select IBUS as the Keyboard Input Method System.

[image: Adding IBus as keyboard input method system @ Language Support]

2) Use Ubuntu Software Centre to install `ibus-hangul`.

3) Shut down and restart.

This should put a second keyboard icon in the top panel.

Click on it and select Preferences. Go to the Input Method tab and select Korean. Click Add.

[image: Adding Korean input method @ IBus preferences]

Now when you click on this second keyboard icon you can select Korean and a Korean icon will appear.

You can activate or deactivate the keyboard switching method by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Now if only I knew some Korean I could show off my success.

(사랑 우분투)

By the way this should work for Chinese as that is the other input method option.

Regards.

Answer (score 6):

In the Unity Launcher, type in input. You will see a few options.

[image]

First go to Language Support. You should be able to select different formats to add to you profile by clicking "Install/Remove Languages".

After you have done this, you should be able to toggle between english and korean at the top right of your screen, next to your time and volume control.

If you are still having issues, type in Input once again from the unity launcher, and start

From there, I would also go to "Input Method Switcher"

Best of Luck!

Comment: I did every thing as you stated, but my ibus keyboard icon says I "No input window" when I have already added Korean. and I have Installed the languages and repeated the steps, ibus continues to say "No input windows". Is their any other way to get the Korean keyboard?

Answer (score 4):

**It's 2021** and the instructions have changed again.

1. From Settings, open Language and Region
2. Select Manage Installed Languages
3. Click Install/Remove Languages
4. Add Korean
5. Reboot your computer
6. Open Settings -> Language and Region again
7. Click the `+` sign
8. Add Korean (Hangul)
9. Click the Gear icon beside (Korean Hangul), and enable "Start in Hangul mode"

To type in Korean, you can now hit Super + Space to swap between languages. The input method will also appear in your tray bar.

---

If these instructions change again, Linuxreviews.org should have the latest: https://linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_get_Korean_input_on_Ubuntu

Also, if you get confused, here's a [video](https://odysee.com/@LinuxReviewsKr:9/Ubuntu-21.04-Korean-Tutorial) guide.

Answer (score 2):

지 금 한국어 를  쓸 수있지 만 the spacing seems uncontrollable, so the syllables are breaking incorrectly.  I wanted the first two symbols together, one word, meaning "now," but the input method kept splitting them apart.

At any rate, I had the same problem as Jorge, and already had steps 1-3 in Jame's response completed without any effect.

His answer inspired me to do the following, which got me to able to access Korean input, albeit with the problem identified above.

1. Typed "input" into the dash, bringing up the screen above (in Jame's response).
2. Clicked "input method switcher," and changed from default to use Ibus.
3. When I closed this window, the wizard advised me to read a file (/usr/share/doc/im-switch/README.Debian.gz) and restart.
4. I opened a terminal and tried reading the suggested file. The information did not seem relevant to Ibus, but suggested that the input method may be an area causing some bugs--something I might still need to consult.  Then I restarted my system.
5. I then clicked on the Ibus keyboard at the top left of my screen, and then preferences.
6. In the preference window, I clicked on the middle tab "Input Method."
7. Then I clicked on the "Select an input method," which gave me the choice of Korean or Chinese.  I clicked on the Korean.
8. Then clicked "ADD."
9. Then I had the ability to switch from English to Korean! 그래 서 너 무 행복한다! Except for this weird spacing issue.  Anyone have ideas for fixing the spacing?
   Doug

Comment: The spacing issue no longer seems to happen. Although this was an old answer so that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

All I needed was

```
sudo apt install ibus-hangul fonts-unfonts-core
```

and a restart and I can finally see Korean characters

To add it as a keyboard option:

- Settings -> Region & Language -> Input Sources -> + -> Other -> Korean (Hangul) -> Add
- Korean (Hangul) settings -> Start in Hangul mode -> OK
- Windows Key + Space to swith between input sources

[Source](https://linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_get_Korean_input_on_Debian)

Answer (score -1):

The Ubuntu hangul method is available with UIM and Fcitx.
You will be able to write Korean without errors.

```
sudo apt install uim
sudo apt install uim uim-byeoru
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Fcitx_5

```
sudo apt-get install fcitx fcitx-mozc fcitx-hangul  fcitx-frontend-qt5 fcitx-frontend-gtk2 fcitx-frontend-gtk3 fcitx-config-gtk fcitx-ui-classic
```

Comment: fcitx4 is deprecated, so suggesting it in this context today (May 2023) is bad advice. Can you please replace fcitx with fcitx5. (Btw, what has mozc to do with it?)