# Screen frozen on boot

Tags: boot, crash, fcitx

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3LTS installed on my computer.

Trying to install a Korean keyboard, I first followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/81711/1035987), which didn't work, then I installed `Fcitx` according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/839863/1035987). After rebooting and configuring the `Language Support`, I switched the keyboard to Korean and the screen froze. I still had control over the mouse cursor, but the environment didn't respond.

After rebooting, the screen gets stuck indefinitely on the splash screen.

Following advice from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1020732/1035987), I booted in recovery mode and ran `sudo fsck -f /`, which seemed to fail – even if I run the command multiple times as recommended, I keep getting the same error message (translated from French, so may not be 100% accurate):

```
/def/sda2 is mounted
e2fsck: Cannot continue, immediate stop
```

Continuing the advice, I edited `etc/default/grub` and removed the `silent splash` options in order to troubleshoot further.

The boot process seems to go fine, every action is labled with a green `[  OK  ]` and the process ends with this line:

```
[  OK  ] Started User Manager for UID 1000.
```

It makes sense this would be the last step in the boot process. After that, I can see and move the mouse cursor on screen, but not use it in any meaningful way.

What actions can I take to debug any further and possibly solve the issue?

Comment: Perhaps boot from a LiveUSB and then run fsck ? Options are shown in http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/fsck.8.html and if you are uncomfortable en Anglais, https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/ may help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, as I suspected the issue was linked to the installation of `fcitx-hangul`.

I opened `tty` using `ctrl`+`alt`+`F2` and removed `fcitx` and its dependencies, and was able to boot without any further issue.

I have no further insight as to why `fcitx` crashes my system, but reinstalling `fcitx-hangul` crashed my system again as soon as I switched the keyboard layout to Korean, and then again on boot.